# Can MacOs Apple ID and iMessage app Apple ID be different?

Tags: macos, apple-id, messages-in-icloud

If my Mac is not signed in to iCloud and I sign in to iMessage (left), does that *only* sign in to iMessage, or does it also set the Apple ID for MacOs and sign the whole machine into iCloud (right)?

Similarly can the two Apple IDs shown below be different?

[image]

If the answer is version-specific, my MacOs version is 10.15.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can be different, I've run a Mac like this since iMessage came to macOS without issue.

Sign into the Messages app to just use Messages with that Apple ID (and sign into FaceTime if you want to use that ID with FaceTime too), then sign into the Apple ID preference pane in System Preferences.

Comment: Are you sure that System Preferences dialog is not for iCloud - I thought Messages and iCloud are the same login - the login for AppStore and Music/iTunes can be different. I have Mojave and BugSur so don't have that System Preferences

Comment: @mmm The System Preferences pane shown is for iCloud, that’s correct. It can be separate to iMessage and FaceTime. I’ve been doing this for years, also with separate iTunes/App Store and iCloud IDs. Mojave has the iCloud preference pane, Big Sur has the Apple ID preference pane, but it functions the same.

Comment: @mmmmmm I have confirmed grg is correct, the Apple IDs you use for Messages and Facetime are used only for those respective apps.  Messages does use iCloud, using *its* specified account, to sync messages.  That can be different from the iCloud account used for other system things.

Comment: Facetime behaves curiously.  It does not use iCloud directly for anything except maybe some background work to find and connect calls.  It does however rely on Contacts, but not  Contacts from the iCloud account it's signed into.  It uses contacts from the System's Contacts, and if the system is signed in to iCloud it will see contacts from *that* account.  Grg I tested this a little, can you confirm it?